# How to dowload audio file mp3 or mp4 or mpeg from firebase database by URL

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

In my class adapter i have ImageView  which must download songs depends on the extension mp3, mp4-mpeg. My firebase database looks like this:

[image: my database picture witch musicUrl]

I can't understand why the download does not start this is method:

```
private void musicdownload(String uri, String title){
    try {

        File musicStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_MUSIC), "Gladia");

        if (!musicStorageDir.exists()){
            musicStorageDir.mkdir();

        }

        //Default Extension mp3
        String musicExtension = ".mp3";
        if (uri.contains(".mp4")){
            musicExtension = ".mp4";
        }else if (uri.contains(".aac")){
            musicExtension = ".aac";
        }else if (uri.contains(".mpeg")){
            musicExtension = ".mpeg";
        }

        String singName = title + musicExtension;

        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(uri);

        Log.d(TAG, "musicdownload: downloadUri: " + downloadUri);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);

        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(DIRECTORY_MUSIC + File.separator, singName)
                .setTitle(singName).setDescription(title)
                .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

        downloadManager.enqueue(request);


    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

*the method call*

```
    viewHolder.download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            musicdownload(music.getMusicUrl(), music.getMusicTitle());
        }
    });
```

Comment: new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);

Comment: Where does it fail/stop?

Comment: @MadaManu the download does not launch the application does not crash

Comment: Any debugging information? Does the execution of the code stop at a particular line? can you put in some breakpoints and see where it doesn't go to?

Comment: Thanks, i see the problem. I had not activated the authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i see the problem. I had not activated the authorization.

Comment: Could you detail more on the authorization and what you did to "activate" it so others coming here will be able to check if they are missing the same thing?

Comment: Access storage permission

Comment: You should update this answer with the more detailed explanation and then close the question. :)